# Installing Ubuntu

Tags: installation, hard-drive

I have an old computer and wanted to install Ubuntu 12.04.3. My problem is it won't even detect the Hard Drive to install the OS after the screen displays the Ubuntu install screen. I am new to Linux and wish to learn more about it, but installing it just gives me a black screen, doesn't show that it is installing, and stays on this black screen with letters from the HD sectors. Please help.

Comment: How old is system. Full Ubuntu with Unity needs a better system and video. How much RAM and what video card/chip do you have?   Older systems may be better with the 32 bit version of Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect that the problem could be due age, then you could always try Ubuntu on a [live USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). Make sure that you are using the latest version available and you have enough space on the memory stick. Personally I recomend anything with 4gb and over to eliminate memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your hard drive is not formatted. You need to start Ubuntu again from your CD or flash drive but do not try to install it yet! When you get to the desktop you need to start a program called Gparted. If it is not there then open up package manager and install it.

Now run Gparted and see if it detects your hard drive.  If it does then delete any partitions that are on it first. Then click Apply. Now you need to create a new partition table so you will click on Device (at the top of Gparted screen), then click on Create Partition Table and choose the entire drive for a new partition. Then click Apply again and you should see that the drive is correctly partitioned. This will make it easy 
for Ubuntu to see it. Now the Ubuntu install can go ahead.